# What is the name of a field theory with modular values?

Tags: field-theory

If you take a simple scalar field, for example, $\phi(x)$ it takes on values from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$ at each point in space.

Is there a name for a field theory where the fields take on values only within a certain range. e.g. like an angle:

$$\phi(x) = \phi(x)+2\pi$$

(Modulus $2\pi$)

If such a classical field could exist, what might it represent?

**Edit:** I guess the same as above would be to have a 2-vector field $A_i(x)$ together with the constraint $|A(x)|^2=1$. Where $\phi(x)$ would be the angle of the vector. So maybe the Lagrangian would be $L = \partial^\mu A(x) . \partial_\mu A(x) + \lambda(x) (|A(x)|^2-1)$. Is it of any use for anything?

Comment: You could take the field theory of a complex scalar field and decompose it into two real fields fields representing the complex magnitude and complex phase. The phase field would be modulo $2\pi$.

Comment: How about a $U(1)$ [non-linear sigma model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-linear_sigma_model)?

Comment: @G.Smith Yes. That's exactly what I mean. What are they used for?

Comment: According to [this article](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Nonlinear_Sigma_model), “The O(3) NLSM model can be interpreted as the continuum limit of an isotropic ferromagnet in statistical mechanics.” I suppose the $U(1)$ model would describe a 2D ferromagnet.

Comment: @G.Smith I understand most of those words but not necessarily in that order. I guess I would have to know more about ferromagnets and statistical mechanics to make head or tail of it.

Comment: A bunch of interacting magnetic dipoles.

Comment: Hmm. Also I'm not sure I get what it means about string theory. Since that seem to be a map from a worldsheet to 10D space. Rather than the other way round.

Comment: So the field would give the rotation of the dipoles I guess and we approximate that as a continuum.

Comment: I can’t help you with the string theory. I believe you have the right idea that the field value specifies the orientation of the magnetic dipole at each point in space.

Comment: model with global O(2) symmetry is famous XY-model, as it was mentioned. Then, model with local O(2) symmetry corresponds to compact QED, which demonstrates confinement in 3D and in 4D. There is a variety of different models and you can check book "Multivalued fields in QFT, cond-mat and gravity" by H. Kleinert